# problem in accessing contents of the file using javascript with tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, file, tomcat

The following code is inside `<script>` tag of `index.html` of my application and it works fine (basically the code is inside a function which gets called when a user clicks on a download button from the UI;the files are already present on the server/location mentioned below) when I access my app via web browser in the following manner:

```
file:///C:/jack/testing/ui/static/index.html
```

By works, I mean, I can see the 3 files getting downloaded in csv format with 3KB of size.

```
const requests = [
  'file1_1555077233.csv',
  'file2_1555077233.csv',
  'file3_1555077233.csv'
].map(file => {
  return fetch('file:///C:/jack/file/JACK/' + file)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch(console.error)
})

Promise.all(requests)
  .then(contents => {
    const zip = new JSZip()

    contents.forEach((content, index) => {
      zip.file(`file-${index}.csv`, content)
    })

    return zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
  })
  .then(blob => {
    saveAs(blob, 'files.zip')
  })
```

**Scenario 1:**

However, when I have my application deployed as WAR file in tomcat, I access my application in the following manner from the web browser :

```
 http://localhost:8080/testing/index.html
```

In this scenario, the above javascript doesn't completely work. I mean, it downloads the 3 files but the size of the file is empty. This makes sense since I am accessing the website over HTTP and my files 
  should be served by the server.

On windows, how should I modify this line of code `return fetch('file:///C:/jack/file/JACK/' + file)` so that it starts working in this scenario.

**Scenario 2:**

Similarly, when I deployed the WAR in the tomcat running on RHEL server, I am accessing my application in the following manner:

```
https://myserver.com/testing/index/html
```

In this scenario also, I am noticing empty files are getting downloaded when I used the above code with this change:

```
  return fetch('/srv/users/JACK' + file)
```

`Scenario #1` is just used for my local testing and it's okay if it doesn't work for me because I can understand that I may not be able to access the files from my local directory. However, in `Scenario 2`, on RHEL server, I am trying to access the files from `srv/users/JACK` directory which isn't local or specific to any user. Why I am still seeing 3 empty csv files getting downloaded in this scenario? Please advise what would be best course of action to overcome this scenario.

Comment: Please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks. Are you trying to point out any mistake in my post by sharing the link to the documentation ? I didn't quite understand how my file access related issue is related to the link. Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: You made no mistake - your question is very well written. Your issue is not so much about file access as it is about understanding how we access Resources using the HTTP protocol through the use of Locators in a Uniform way (URLs). Your files are resources, you are using HTTP, and that requires that you use URLs (your _true_ question) correctly for any of this to work. Hope that helps.